# Erlang timer does not return ontime

Tags: timer, erlang

I have the following Erlang function which calls another function and waits 
for 40 seconds and then prints something,
the problem is that when i try to run the program the it takes lot more time than 
40 second for the receive statement to return to the Erlang shell.
What could be the cause of this issue?

```
reboot_node_return(Sc) ->
    linux(Sc, "reboot -f"),
    receive _ -> ok
    after 40000 -> 
        io:format("successfull reboot:~n")
end.
```

-A

Comment: Is linux/2 an asynchronous function?

Comment: I am not sure, the linux/2 just calls a system command on a linux cluster using the Erlang os:cmd/1 function. So i think it is an asynchronous function.

Comment: The problem is solved now, i was using an ssh connection to run the reboot command on the remote cluster and since i was using the -f the ssh was waiting for the command to be done, and this caused the function to wait more time than i have given in sleep function.

Comment: If you have figured out what the answer to your original question was, please add it as an answer below and accept it.  If your original question was invalid, please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
reboot_node_return(Sc) ->
    linux(Sc, "reboot "),
    receive _ -> ok
    after 40000 -> 
        io:format("successfull reboot:~n")
end.
```